# In react-page ORY editor, is there a way to get html string output with inline styles?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, html-renderer

A quick note: Since I do not have enough reputations, I cannot create new relevant tags related to ORY Editor. I'm not sure whether this question will reach the right people.

While using [react-page](https://github.com/react-page/react-page) currently, we can get a HTML string output by using:

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
  <HTMLRenderer state={editorValue} plugins={plugins} />
)
```

However, this exports the HTML tags with pre-defined "class" names, which are then styled using the CSS files imported in the code.

I'm trying to implement something, where I use react-page/ORY on a web-page. Export the HTML, and render this is a mobile app, using react-native. CSS files cannot used in mobile app development.

Now there is no easy solution to when it comes to CSS files of react-page/ORY, because all the CSS files are distributed all along the node-modules in separate folders.

I even tried:
- putting a bunch of these CSS files in a single folder,
- creating a .html file, and importing these CSS files in that .html file,
- opening this .html file now on browser clearly shows CSS files weren't applied, maybe because of distributed nature of CSS files.

So, any ideas on getting inline-styled HTML as export from react-page/ORY?